# Kendo UI Menu using customized SiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-menu

I am trying to customize XMLSiteMap for Kendo UI Menu to include more properties other than title, controller, action, area.

But XMLSiteMap didn't provide any override method to implement custom properties.Can we add more properties to SiteMap file? Is it possible to have custom XmlSiteMapProvider for Kendo UI Menu?

Any inputs will be helpful to proceed.

Thanks,
Siva